# Issue with button in a Html/Css table and Mysql

Tags: html, css, mysql, button, html-table

I have a small problem. Right now I'm programming a website, which is connected to a mysql database.
I created a table filled with products, which are stored in the database. Each row has a Button "Add to Cart" but how do I exactly get the specific item for it? I already have the function `addtoCart(string articleName)` but I don't know how to get the name of the product.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<table id="Products">
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
              </tr>
    <% 

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop", "root", "12345");
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT* FROM products WHERE category='shisha'");

      while(rs.next()){
      int id = rs.getInt("articleID");
      String pname = rs.getString("productName");
      String description= rs.getString("description");
      float price = rs.getFloat("price");
      int stock = rs.getInt("stock");
      %>
              <tr>
                <td><%out.print(id);%></td>
                <td><%out.print(pname);%></td>
                <td><%out.print(description);%></td>
                <td><%out.print(price);%></td>
                <td><%out.print(stock);%></td>
                <td> </td>  
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="How much ?" name="quantity" required> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type = "submit" value="Add to cart"> </td>
               </tr>
      <%
      }



      %>
      </table>
```

So it generates a row for each product with its own button.... I want to call the function `addtoCart(string articleName)` but how do I get the product name of the row the button is in?

Comment: This question could be answered with a basic search, please refrain from asking questions until you know how to look up basic documentation for the tools you are using, thank you https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery you could add a class and data attribute to your button, you could then get the value like so.

```
<input class="button" data-product="<%out.print(pname);%>" type = "submit" value="Add to cart">

 $('.button').click(function(){

  var product = $(this).data("product");
   addtoCart(product);

 });
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add it to the button. Instead of making the button a submit button, create a

```
<button onclick="addToCart(%out.print(id);%);">Add to cart</button>
```

then get the product information in a function called addToCart